# How to avoid creating custom exception classes whilst still throwing exceptions at an appropriate level of abstraction?

Tags: java, exception

I'm reviewing my understanding of exception handling (in the context of Java), and trying to figure out what types of exceptions are most appropriate to throw. One comment that I'm regularly seeing is that it is generally better to avoid creating many custom exceptions - it is better to use the "widely understood" standard exceptions, and only "create a custom exception type when you need to annotate the exception with additional information to aid in the programmatic handling of the symptom."

However, this seems somewhat in contrast to the idea that you should "throw exceptions at the right level of abstraction". Looking at an example from Uncle Bob's 'Clean Code' the following examples are provided for an Employee class:

```
Bad: public TaxId getTaxId() throws EOFException
Good: public TaxId getTaxId() throws EmployeeDataNotAvailable
```

So, how do I consolidate these two "recomendations" - that you should only throw exceptions at the right level of abstraction, and you should rarely create custom exception classes. In addition, when searching for information on the standard exceptions in Java, there is very very little well presented and formatted information on what standard exception classes are available - I'm looking for standard exceptions that would semantically still seem to be appropriate for calling classes, but not finding much to go on. Of course you *can* find the what exception classes are available in the jdk documentation, but just the general lack of info and discussion online seems strange.

So, this is where I'm at right now. Any suggestions and comments are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an specific answer for your question. In my projects, I tend to follow these guidelines for custom exception classes:

- If I can encounter with an exception in a method, check if the exception can be described by any of the subclasses of [`Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) or, if possible, a subclass of [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html). The javadocs provide enough info about the basic classes that extend from both `Exception` and `RuntimeException` and each exception class could also have more subclasses that weren't listed before e.g. `IOException`.
- If there's no subclass of `Exception` or `RuntimeException` or any, create a custom exception class or reuse one previously created but with a distinct message. Usually, I tend to create these classes extending from `RuntimeException` to avoid clients of the method using `try-catch` blocks. If there's the need to handle the exception in the client of this method, then it should extend from `Exception`.

The custom exception classes are associated to a process or specific event in the application.

If developing a business application, then the name of the exception can be related to the business process you're working with. For example, if I'm developing a process that creates a bill from a set of input data (e.g. products, services, customer data, etc), then I would provide at least 2 custom exception classes:

- `ElementNotFoundException`, probably for not finding a specific kind of input e.g. missing product or `Customer#billingAddressLocation` is `null` due to a wrong migration of the data of some customer.
- `BillGenerationException`, generated when there's a problem after collecting the necessary data to generate the bill and in the exact process of generate the bill.

Answer (score 2):

The level of abstraction is judged to be right or wrong **by the user of your code**. To justify an existence of AExeption and BException there should be a use-case where the user differentiates between them, e.g:

```
    } catch(AExeption ae) {
        // do something
    } catch(BException be) {
       // do something different
    }
```

as opposed to always:

```
    } catch(AExeption ae | BException be ) {
        // do something
    }
```

My experience is that real world systems tend to go easy on the amount of logic that goes into *the programmatic handling of the symptom*

Answer (score 1):

It's quite philosophical question.

But in general it means that you should create your own exception with considering of existing ones.

Example :

> In case of usage some external service and this service is unavailable
>   , in this case I wouldn't recommend you to throw your own exception,
>   because "Connection Refused" or "Connection timed out" will understand
>   on the spot every programmer after you, for checking your custom
>   exception programmer will need to go to source code and spend some
>   time to understand your exception after noticing it in production
>   logs.

But if I see that my wrapper will be clearer for such case I am adding my wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

There is no contradiction between using exceptions of the right level of abstraction and refraining from creating new exception classes.  What you must do is choose the most appropriate existing exception class for the particular method you are interested in *if you can*.

So if the clear meaning of a `getTaxiId` method does not suggest the method  performs I/O, declaring it to throw an `IOException` of any kind would be inappropriate. You would then have to search the other existing exception classes for a more approriate exception class. If you did not find such a class, you know it is appropriate to create a new exception class.

Answer (score 1):

I think Uncle Bob is looking at the problem from the wrong end.
You throw an exception to unravel the call chain and inform a non-local piece of logic that something unexpected and detrimental happened and allow it to respond.

I can understand wrapping an `EOFException` and all sorts of bad data problems into some generic `InvalidDataException` but providing a specific `EmployeeDataException` seems like overkill.
It may be useful for the calling process to (say) know that there was a local data exception and not, for example, a lost connection. That way it could abandon a unit of work but realistically continue trying to process the next one.

So, do throw at an appropriate level of abstraction - for the catcher to respond usefully.

If you think about it, if you create a different exception for each object type, someone will have to maintain catchers for all object types in play! 
Tomorrow a new exception called `AddressDataException` is introduced and various (obscure) catcher chains need that added as yet-another-data-exception category.
Of course the answer is to introduce a `DataException` category as super-class to all those specialised ones.
But as soon as you do that you'll change all the handlers to catch the generic exception and  realise that the correct level of abstraction is a generic `DataException` because that's what is useful to the catcher.